# Passing an Object in a Function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am doing a freecodecamp challenge and I am being asked to finish writing a function that returns true if the object passed contains all four names: 'Alan' 'Jeff' 'Ryan' 'Sarah'.
an Object is defined earlier, containing the data :

```
let users = {
    Alan: {
      age: 27,
      online: true
    },
    Jeff: {
      age: 32,
      online: true
    },
```

etc.
the function begins like this

```
function isEveryoneHere(userObj) {}
```

and I have this written as my completed function, in which I am able to return all 4 names:

```
for (const property in userObj) {
  if (userObj) {
    return userObj.hasOwnProperty(property)
  }
```

But I am still being told that I am not meeting the criteria of the challenge. Any pointers or tips of advice?

> edit: Error Message The users object should not be accessed directly
>
> Passed The users object should only contain the keys Alan, Jeff,
> Sarah, and Ryan
>
> Passed The function isEveryoneHere should return true if Alan, Jeff,
> Sarah, and Ryan are properties on the object passed to it.
>
> The function isEveryoneHere should return false if Alan is not a
> property on the object passed to it.
>
> The function isEveryoneHere should return false if Jeff is not a
> property on the object passed to it.
>
> The function isEveryoneHere should return false if Sarah is not a
> property on the object passed to it.
>
> The function isEveryoneHere should return false if Ryan is not a
> property on the object passed to it

edit:

this is how they solved it

```
function isEveryoneHere(userObj) {
  if (
    userObj.hasOwnProperty("Alan") &&
    userObj.hasOwnProperty("Jeff") &&
    userObj.hasOwnProperty("Sarah") &&
    userObj.hasOwnProperty("Ryan")
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error message that says you're not meeting the criteria?

Comment: @PaulinaKhew it's probably one/more test objects it's being tested with don't return proper result. Usually it doesn't tell you what data it's trying on the function to avoid cheating ;)

Comment: **Added** sorry about that. 

I think that it wants me to add a boolean in my parameters for my if statement. However I attempted initially by writing an if statement saying:
if (userObj) {
userObj.hasOwnProperty('online')}
and other attempts which didn't get me a pass so then I tried doing a for...in statement and an if statement after doing some research on what I could solution I could possibly offer.

Comment: the error message saying you shouldnt access the object directly...   in your function you call: userObj.hasOwnProperty(property).  Which is calling a function within the object directly.   Try extracting the keys from the object using var keyArray = Object.keys(userObj);  Then checking that the key Array has only the names listed and isnt missing any

Comment: ```const keys = Object.keys(users);```

```const all_here = ['Alan', 'Jeff', 'Sarah', 'Ryan'].every(el => keys.includes(el));```
Does this help?

Comment: @Robert Rocha it still leaves me undefined.

Comment: And @DynasticSponge that helped give me a sense of things. I tried to use it in a for loop, but to no avail. I think I'll keep on working with that binding that extracted the keys to see how much further I can get.

Comment: Where does it leave you undefined?

Comment: @Robert Rocha I think it is because I am not using 'in' or the .hasOwnProperty() command

Comment: this is how they solved it lmaoo...
function isEveryoneHere(userObj) {
  if (
    userObj.hasOwnProperty("Alan") &&
    userObj.hasOwnProperty("Jeff") &&
    userObj.hasOwnProperty("Sarah") &&
    userObj.hasOwnProperty("Ryan")
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do something like

```js
let users = {
    Alan: {
      age: 27,
      online: true
    },
    Jeff: {
      age: 32,
      online: true
    },
}

function check(userObj) {
  return ['Alan', 'Jeff', 'Ryan', 'Sarah'].every(user => userObj.hasOwnProperty(user));
}

function check2(userObj) {
  return ['Alan', 'Jeff', 'Ryan', 'Sarah'].every(user => Object.keys(userObj).includes(user));
}

console.log('check: ' + check({ Jeff: 1, Alan: 2, Ryan: 3, Sarah: 4 }));
console.log('check2: ' + check2({ Jeff: 1, Alan: 2, Ryan: 3, Sarah: 4 }));
console.log('Should fail (check): ' + check(users));
console.log('Should fail (check2): ' + check2(users));
```

both variants should satisfy all criteria - except the one that the object should not be accessed directly. I am not sure what they mean by that, but the second one transforms the keys into an array, so maybe that's what they are looking for, even though it's inefficient.

Comment: This does not satisfy the answer. What it means by "object should not be accessed directly" they mean that I can use 'users' in my function, I must use userObj.

Comment: Oh wow, ok... that's easy then. I edited the code snippet to reflect that, just pass in the users object to any of the functions ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Spec describes [includes](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes) function as linear search. So when you use it in any loop then it will increase its worst-case time complexity to `n * 2`. If you need to check for the existence of a name then you can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) here which is optimized for an existence check.

To make an optimized solution you can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) here

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function isEveryoneHere(userObj) {
  const nameDict = ['Alan', 'Jeff', 'Sarah', 'Ryan'];
  const keys = new Set(Object.keys(userObj));
  return nameDict.every(name => keys.has(name))
}

console.log(isEveryoneHere(users));
```

Comment: this gave me the right answer, but I didn't use any of the commands that it asked for me to. Either way thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ran this through the link and it passed

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function isEveryoneHere(userObj) {
  const names = ['Alan', 'Jeff', 'Ryan', 'Sarah'];
  const keys = Object.keys(userObj);
  for (let name in names) {
    if (!(name in keys)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isEveryoneHere(users));
```

It loops through each name in `names` and checks if the `users` object contains a key that is equivalent to that name. If any name isn't in `keys`, it returns `false`. Otherwise, it returns `true`.

Comment: this returns true but the requirements are not met.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-data-structures/check-if-an-object-has-a-property

Comment: @goldwind1111 edited it with an answer that passed :)

Comment: Nice job :) Thanks for your help too. I'm going to add you as a friend. I've always got plenty of questions lol :))

Answer (score 0):

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
};
const myProps = ['Alan', 'Jeff', 'Sarah', 'Ryan'];

function isEveryoneHere(userObj, expectedProps) {
    return expectedProps.every(el => Object.keys(userObj).includes(el));
}

console.log(isEveryoneHere(users, myProps))
```

Posting this as the answer vs a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isEveryoneHere(userObj) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if (
    "Alan" in userObj &&
    "Jeff" in userObj &&
    "Sarah" in userObj &&
    "Ryan" in userObj
    )
    {
    return true;
  } else{
    return false;
  }
  // Only change code above this line
}
```

Alternatively to .hasOwnProperty you can use the 'x in obj' method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code below will always return `true`.

```
for (const property in userObj) {
  if (userObj) {
    return userObj.hasOwnProperty(property)
  }
```

You are looping all existing properties in `userObj` and then checking if that property exists from the same object you are looping on. At the very first iteration of the `for in` loop, this will always return `true`.

What you want is to check if **ALL** the property keys , 'Alan' 'Jeff' 'Ryan' 'Sarah', actually exists. There's a lot of ways to do this. One way is with utilizing some array functions:

```
function isEveryoneHere(userObj)  {
  return ['Alan', 'Jeff', 'Ryan', 'Sarah'].map(key => userObj.hasOwnProperty(key)).reduce((a, b) => a && b, true);
}
```